# Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, vps

After a long time of research on Internet I found nothing...

I'm trying to start Nginx on an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS:

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

When I look in `journalctl -xe` here is what I get:

```
[date] [terminal name] sshd[16465]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
[date] [terminal name] sshd[16465]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=200.108.
[date] [terminal name] sshd[16465]: Failed password for invalid user info from 200.108.143.6 port 35460 ssh2
[date] [terminal name] sshd[16465]: Received disconnect from 200.108.143.6 port 35460:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
[date] [terminal name] sshd[16465]: Disconnected from invalid user info 200.108.143.6 port 35460 [preauth]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd go with what the log shows regarding "authentication failure"... How does your configuration file look, did you setup the configs with proper authentication? Just a hint for a starting point and nothing more perhaps.

Comment: what does `journalctl -u nginx.service` say?